# How come my 'click' eventListener works for the first 2 <li>'s and not the rest?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am relatively new to programming. I got my 'click' eventListener to work, and when you click on the first two li's in the ul, the class of the div toggles on and off. However, when you click on any li after the second one, it toggles the class of every other div and not the one that is clicked on? If you need more clarification regarding the situation, feel free to let me know.

For example, if the for loop were to print:

- Bench Press
- Deadlift
- Squat
- Shoulder press
- Curl

If i click on 'bench press' and 'deadlift' it will toggle .info and show the information for it; but if i were to click on 'squat' it will toggle .info for the 'curl' instead, so on and so forth...

Here is all the code,

```html
<div>
    {% for workout in workouts %}
    <ul>
        <li class="item">{{ workout.name }}</li>

        {% autoescape false %}
        <div class="info" id="info">
            <p>{{ workout.description }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endautoescape %}
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

```js
let li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
let info = document.querySelectorAll(".info");

for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    info[i].classList.toggle("info");
  });
}
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: If you're sure your HTML preprocessor is working, it'd be better to post its output, just the HTML, so we can run the code without an unverifiable mysterious layer that might or might not be part of the problem (i.e. [mcve]). Are you sure `document.querySelectorAll("li");` isn't picking up any other `<li>`s on the page? This is a pretty broad selector. I'd have a single wrapper that you select for each `<li>`. To that end, the `<div>` should be a child of the `<li>`, then extract child elements. The HTML is invalid as is.

Comment: I don't know what code your preprocessor is actually producing but at first glance it looks as though you might be creating an unordered list that has non-li elements as direct children.

Comment: your HTML is very likely messed up because, as well as what @AHaworth notes, you have start and end tags in weird places with regard to your loop and `if` constructs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code is fine.

**Make sure your HTML is valid.**

Each html tag has to be properly closed.
So ether `<tag />` or `<tag> </tag>`, when the browser encounters what it deems incomplete, it will attempt to patch things up, that could cause your `<li>` and `<div>` pairs to misalign.

I saw you've edited your question, so it might not be relevant anymore.

*note that you debug and inspect the actual html the browser has interpreted, `rightclick-> inspect` will open a view where you can see the state of the browser*

```js
let li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
let info = document.querySelectorAll(".info");

for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    info[i].classList.toggle("info");
  });
}
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}

.info-colour {
  background: chocolate;
}

.item {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background: orange;
}

p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div>

  <ul>
    <li class="item"> workout.name 1</li>
    <div class="info info-colour">
      <p> workout.description 1 </p>
      <div>
        Necessary Workout Equpiment: [Specific Machinery]
      </div>
    </div>


    <li class="item">workout.name 2</li>
    <div class="info info-colour">
      <p> workout.description 2 </p>
      <div>
        Necessary Workout Equpiment: [Specific Machinery]
      </div>
    </div>


    <li class="item">workout.name 3</li>
    <div class="info info-colour">
      <p> workout.description 3 </p>
      <div>
        Necessary Workout Equpiment: [Specific Machinery]
      </div>
    </div>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML here is still invalid. Plop it into https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea. OP hasn't provided a minimal example, so this is basically the same code as OP already has, with the `<ul>` location adjusted, but that (probably) doesn't matter. It's very likely the issue is that OP has `<li>`s somewhere else on the page, throwing off the count of the brittle "parallel arrays" strategy they're using to map their list to their info divs.

Answer (score -1):

The `i` variable stores the last value after the loop, since it is in another callback function.

Try this fix:

```
let li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  let liItem = li[i];
  liItem.addEventListener("click", function () {
    liItem.querySelector("div").classList.toggle("info");
  });
}
```

Comment: This isn't true here, because the loop uses `let` rather than `var`. Also, even if this was [one of those problematic cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), your adjustment here would do nothing to fix it.